# Magento 2 oveeride style-m.less

Tags: magento-2.1, less-css

I want to override the **body{}** tag of `style-m.css` in my theme.

The code of `.themename.less` in `vendor\theme\web\css\source` is

```
body {
      .lib-background-gradient(
        #004b6e,
        @main-theme-color,
        vertical,
        true
    );
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
}
```

but I cant see the changes.On inspect element the word-wrap property in not applied on body.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` command and then check.

Comment: thank you, it worked. I was deploying static content without setup:upgrade.